# Is it possible to maintain ordering in JSON while converting it from xml and vice versa

Tags: java, xml, json

I need to convert XML to JSON and then after applying some business logic need to reconvert back in XML,
But when i try to convert a XML to JSON and then reconvert back the JSON back to XML I am getting its attributes in Different order.

Eg Following XML

`<breakfast_menu><food><name>Belgian Waffles</name><price>$5.95</price></food></breakfast_menu>`

is converted to following JSON

```
{"breakfast_menu":{"food":{"price":"$5.95","name":"Belgian Waffles"}}}
```

and is reconverted to following XML

```
<breakfast_menu><food><price>$5.95</price><name>Belgian Waffles</name></food></breakfast_menu>
```

As there is name tag is replaced by price tag .

Is there any way so that we can maintain ordering so the conversion and reconversion produce same output .

```
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

`import org.json.XML;`

```
public class XmlToJson {


 public static int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;
    public static String TEST_XML_STRING =
            "<breakfast_menu>\n" +
                    "<food>\n" +
                    "<name>Belgian Waffles</name>\n" +
                    "<price>$5.95</price>\n" +
                    "</food>\n" +
                    "</breakfast_menu>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);
            String jsonString = xmlJSONObj.toString();
            System.out.println(jsonString);
            System.out.println("================================");
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            String s1 = XML.toString(jsonObj);

            System.out.println(s1);
            s1 = s1.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
            TEST_XML_STRING = TEST_XML_STRING.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
            System.out.println("================================");
            System.out.println(TEST_XML_STRING);
            System.out.println("================================");

            System.out.println(s1.equals(TEST_XML_STRING));



        } catch (JSONException je) {
            System.out.println(je.toString());
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Maybe you should describe "then after applying some business logic", I mean the conversion XML > JSON > XML seems like "over processing"

Comment: JSON has no notion of ordering in objects; so the canonical answer is "no". However, some JSON libraries allow to specify an order in object members, such as Jackson.

Comment: By definition, the key/value pairs in a JSON "object" are unordered.  Even if you succeed in achieving an order somehow, there's no guarantee that subsequent processing won't reorder things.

Answer (score 1):

It might be naturally wrong because by default the definition of JSON is:

```
An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.
```

However, you might want to check [JSON.simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) library which read the JSON string and keep the order of keys

Answer (score 1):

While there are mechanisms that you might use to provide some sort of ordering, `JSON` does not guarantee a processor of any particular order. If you are interfacing with some process that requires a particular order (and that is under your control), I would recommend changing that process so it conforms to the normal JSON process to handle unordered input.